# React routes move sub-routes to separate module?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Is it possible todo the following with React Route?

Main

```
  <Routes handler={App}>
    <Profile path="profile" />
    <Explore path="explore" />
  </Routes>
```

Profile

```
    <Route>
      <Route name="dashboard" handler={ProfileDashboard} />
      <Route name="repos" handler={ProfileRepos} />
    </Route>
```

Explore

```
    <Route>
      <Route name="home" handler={ExploreHome} />
      <Route name="showcase" handler={ExploreShowcase} />
    </Route>
```

Comment: my question is why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with React Router! :)

But I would suggest you to check it out the "plain routes" way to configure your routes:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes

Using this, you will start working with a `routes` object, and you can just `require` another routes and create your route based on those combinations. Something like that:

```js
const routes = {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
        require('./profile'),
        require('./explore')
    ]
}
```

Then in your `profile.js` (you can do the same to `explore.js`) file, you will have something like that:

```js
/* Import the ProfileDashboard and ProfileRepos here */

const profileRoutes = {
    path: 'profile',
    childRoutes: [{
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: ProfileDashboard
    }, {
        path: 'repos',
        component: ProfileRepos
    }]
};
```

And this way you can achieve what you want.

If you really can't use plain routes, you may do something like that:

```js
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    { require('./profile') }
    { require('./explore') }
</Route>
```

And your `profile.js`, for example:

```js
module.exports = (
    <Route path="profile">
        <Route path="dashboard" component={ProfileDashboard} />
        <Route path="dashboard" component={ProfileRepos} />
    </Route>
);
```

I don't know what React Router version you are using, but you can achieve that in any version, but, as a suggestion, try using the latest one. Since it handle lots of cool stuff.

Hope it helps!

Comment: have you tried this yourself? I tried something like this but it didn't work!

Comment: Yes, it was working. What react / react-router version are you using?

Comment: Yep just tested it out thanks https://github.com/alikor/spike-react-routes